# PHP: Prevent content in iframe from being run

Tags: php

I have a search results page and every result has a link which opens a modal where I display an `iframe` to a PHP file.

```
<a href='#cart<?php echo $i;?>'name="add" onclick='return false>Ajouter</a>
<div id='panier<?php echo $i;?>'>
<iframe src="http://domain.com/addToCart.php?item=<?php echo $item; ?>" 
name = 'myIframe'></iframe>
</div>
```

I need to store `item` every time I open the modal one by one. Then save them in array with `array_push`.

The problem is that all items are displayed from the first modal opening.

Comment: Can you expound further?